# Make image as large as will fit, scaled, even if it needs to be stretched larger

Tags: html, css

I have dynamic content on my webpage with some images I feature. On large screens I have the image floated to the right of the page, and on small screens I treat the image as a block and set its width to 100% of the screen.

That has worked well enough for most images, but sometimes the image is really tall, which makes it hard on small screens where the image is 100% of the screen width and you might have to scroll for a while to get past the image.

To combat that I set a max-height for the image, and have a blurry copy of the image behind the first image that is 100% of the width to fill in the void. (Kind of like what TV stations do when they broadcast in one resolution and show a video with a different resolution).

It works well, except I want the image to be as big as it can, either 100% width or upto the max-height. For small images it just goes as big as the dimensions of the actual image.

```
figure{position:relative;overflow:hidden;float:right;width:202px;margin:0 0 0.5rem 0.5rem;font-size:0;text-align:center}
figure img{margin:auto;max-width:100%;max-height:400px;width:auto;height:auto;display:block;border:0}
figure span{display:block;position:absolute;z-index:-1;filter:blur(10px);-ms-filter:blur(10px);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='10');top:-10px;left:-10px;padding:10px;width:100%;height:100%}
figcaption{text-align:left;background:#fff;font-size:0.75rem}

@media(max-width:528px){
figure{float:none;margin:0 auto;width:100%}
figure img{max-height:300px}}

<figure>
<a href="#"><img src="dynamicPic.jpg">
<span style="background:url(dynamicPic.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover"></span>
</a>
<figcaption>Dynamic Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a little bit of Javascript can do the trick

```
var img = document.getElementById("image-id-here");
img.onload = function(){
    var maxWidth = (document.body.clientHeight / img.height) * img.width;
    var maxHeight = (document.body.clientWidth / img.width) * img.height;
    if(maxWidth > document.body.clientWidth){
        img.width = img.width * (maxHeight / img.height);
        img.height = maxHeight;
    }else{
        img.width = maxWidth
        img.height = img.height * (maxWidth / img.width);
    }
}
```

This should resize the image to the maximum size but still maintain the aspect ratio.

Important: The code above should be ran after the image tag has loaded